# android can't use picasso library

Tags: android

I use Picasso library picasso-2.5.2.jar to load image from url
this is my binderdata

```
public class BinderDataImg extends BaseAdapter {
static final String KEY_IMG = "img";
LayoutInflater inflater;
List<HashMap<String,String>> imgHashmap;
ViewHolder holder;
public BinderDataImg() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
public BinderDataImg(Activity act, List<HashMap<String,String>> map) {
    this.imgHashmap = map;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) act
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return imgHashmap.size();
}
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi=convertView;
    if(convertView==null){
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_img, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.iv_img =(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.imageViewImg);
        vi.setTag(holder);
    }
    else{
        holder = (ViewHolder)vi.getTag();
    }
    String uri = imgHashmap .get(position).get(KEY_IMG);
    Picasso.with(this).load(KEY_IMG).into(holder.iv_img);
    return vi;
}
static class ViewHolder{
    ImageView iv_img;
}
```

}

but error in Picasso.with(this).load(KEY_IMG).into(holder.iv_img)
how to fix it.
sorry for my bad English.
thank you for reading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this point to current i.e BinderDataImg class context you need to pass activity context to load Image

```
Activity act;
public BinderDataImg(Activity act, List<HashMap<String,String>> map) {
    this.imgHashmap = map;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) act
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    this.act = act;
}

Picasso.with(act).load(KEY_IMG).into(holder.iv_img);
```

also check for proper permission for network in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```